# Problem connecting to java ws

Tags: c#, java, .net, web-services

I've created EJB Stateless Bean and have added @WebService, @WebMethod
annotations to be able to access it as web service. I am using
NetBeans and GlassFish. When I tested web services with server console
they worked as expected. Next I've created .net application which is
supposed to be client for my web service. The problem is when I have
more than one method in the web service it does not work. When I
remove all method except one it works ok.
I also created for test purpose not EJB based web service - web
application project with added web service. This version works ok. So
am I suppose to do something at client side or server side to make the
EJB version works?

Comment: without knowing what the wsdl looks like or what your code looks like will make it darn near impossible to answer this question...  do you have control over both ends (the java side too)?  if so - can you post some sample code/wsdl?

Comment: Is the problem on the ESB side when you update it, or the client side? If the ESB, which one are you using? If the client side, which WS approach are you using, such as Axis2 or Jax-WS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless explicitly told to, the web service libraries in Glassfish produce SOAP11 WSDL's, and most .NET-tools expect SOAP12.

If you cannot make your .NET-tool understand SOAP11, it appears you must adapt your sun-javaws.xml file.   I have not tried this myself.

See https://metro.dev.java.net/1.4/docs/soap12.html